# Random file access of stl::map data in C++

Tags: c++, file, dictionary, stl

I have a stl::map data-structure

> key:data pair

which I need to store in a binary file.

- key is an unsigned short value, and is not sequential
- data is another big structure, but is of fixed size.

This map is managed based on some user actions of add, modify or delete. And I have to keep the file updated every time I update the map. This is to survive a system crash scenario.
Adding can always be done at the end of the file. But, user can modify or delete any of the existing records.
That means I have to randomly access the file to update that modified/deleted record.
My questions are:

- Is there a way I can reach the modified record in the file directly without sequentially searching thru the whole records ? ( Max record size is 5000)
- On a delete, how do I remove it from the file and move the next record to the deleted record's position ?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: *"And I have to keep the file updated every time I update the map. This is to survive a system crash scenario."* That's probably not sufficient. Are you flushing the OS's buffer cache? If the system crashes mid-write, are you okay with a corrupted/incomplete file? There's a reason transactional key-value stores exist: they're hard to get right (but extremely useful for some situations).

Comment: Right about now, you really want an embedded database (e.g., [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb)).

Comment: @Cornstalks: yes, I am flushing it.

Comment: @Jerry: I am adding on to an existing application, and its already using this approach, but they had fixed size arrays where data access was easy.  Adding an ext. db wont be an easy option for me

Comment: Given that you're dealing with fixed-size records, I'd probably just keep a list of erased records. When you add a record, insert it in a deleted spot if one's available. Otherwise, append to the end of the file. Then keep an index to establish the real order. When your program closes, write out the index (in its entirety). In case of a crash, the data file will have a newer time-stamp than the index, in which case you need to re-create the index from the data (which obviously needs to include enough to know the order).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jerry. Let me study this option ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no need for the tree structure of std::map and you just need an associative container, the most common way I've seen to do this is to have two files: One with the keys and one with the data. In the key file, it will contain all of they keys along with the corresponding offset of their data in the data file. Since you said the data is all of the same size, updating should be easy to do (since it won't change any of the offsets). Adding is done by appending. Deleting is the only hard part; you can delete the key to remove it from the database, but it's up to you if you want to keep track of "freed" data sections and try to write over them. To keep track of the keys, you might want another associative container (map or unordered_map) in memory with the location of keys in the key file.

---

Edit: For example, the key file might be (note that offsets are in bytes)

```
key1:0
key2:5
```

and the corresponding data file would be

```
data1data2
```

This is a pretty tried and true pattern, used in everyone from hadoop to high speed local databases. To get an idea of persistence complications you might consider, I would highly recommend reading [this Redis blog](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html), it taught me a lot about persistence when I was dealing with similar issues.

Comment: Thank you sabreitweiser for the answer. Let me read the blog and figure out the possibilities of this solution ...